# How to insert object in array of object data in MySql

Tags: mysql, datatables

I've to insert this array of objects into MySql, this object without the `transaction` would become easy to insert as it would have only 'name' and 'acc' fields so whenever I retrieve data, it comes as a single column. But how to store the `transaction` part by not creating a transaction table for each user, because while getting data I would have to get it from different tables separately.

```
[{
  "user": "Name",
  "acc": 1233423,
  "transactions":{
    "1":"1000",
    "2":"1000",
    "3":"3000"
  }
},{
  "user": "Name",
  "acc": 1233423,
  "transactions":{
    "1":"1000",
    "2":"3000"
  }
}]
```

Comment: You could insert the JSON, see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: _because while getting data I would have to get it from different tables separately_ No you wouldn't Have a look at the JOIN syntax. You do not have to read a relational database like it was a collection of flat files

Comment: @caramba But it would be better placed in a properly designed normalised set of tables

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe yes, maybe no. Depends what he later wants/needs to do with the data. That's why I wrote: "You **could** ..."

Comment: You can use the JSON datatype, but searching and manipulating JSON in SQL is annoyingly complicated. I don't have any direct experience using it, but from all the questions I've seen on SO about it, it seems to be more trouble than it's worth.